# iPad Object Detection

Tags: ipad, detection

I want to build an iPad app that detect an alphabet physical shape placed on the iPad screen and print the alphabet to the screen after processing the object detection. Is this doable?

I am trying to find a way to implement this, but could not find any article or online resource that guide me to that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine you could start by looking at the various pens and stylus's that are available for iPads. Look at how they work. Then you would need to see if you cna make an object that will activate the touch mechanism over a defined area in the same way, for example - a line, and see if you can detech the touch points along the line. Sorting all that out will effectively get you started.

Comment: I found this website http://jumbo-ipawn.nl/ talking about iPad games with physical objects. Unfortunately, I could not found a contact me link to contact the developer. I am wondering how long it takes to develop it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, we managed to do it by assuming objects will have stylus materials at the bottom of the objects and we use that to recognize the object shape.